# React Material Margin in TextFields

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a very simple problem. I've tried to put `marginButtom` on the TextFields. I don't have any idea why it isn't putting any margin on it.

Pls check this codesandbox link

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-margin-yhoqy?file=/src/LoginForm.js)

**CODE**

```
      <label>Schedule</label>
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            name="schedule"
            type="date"
            variant="outlined"
            className={classes.marginButtom}
          />
```

Comment: you have typo in `marginButtom: { marginButtom: "10px" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have a typo in your styles object.

```
  marginButtom: {
    marginButtom: "10px" // It should be marginBottom instead of marginButtom
  },
```